# Use gcc+gtest+mockcpp in windows,the mock does not work at all

Tags: c++, unit-testing, gcc, mocking, googletest

When I build the mockcpp lib mockcpp.lib in MSVC format and build my unit test project in MSVC, it works well.

When I specify the CMake generator for the mockcpp to Unix Makefile, specify native compilers to cygwin64/bin/gcc.exe and cygwin64/bin/g++.exe and set -DMOCKCPP_XUNIT=gtest -DMOCKCPP_XUNIT_HOME=googletest-release/googletest, I get the libmockcpp.a after build the mockcpp.

But when I build my unit test project in gcc, the mock function does not work at all. I use GDB to debug it and find it still run into the mult_num function which I mocked.

Is there any macro or other option should be add when use gcc to compile mockcpp?

Thanks.

The sample test code:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <mockcpp/mokc.h>

int add_num(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int mult_num(int a, int b)
{
    return a * b;
}
int add_mult(int a, int b)
{
    int sum = add_num(a,b);
    if (sum == mult_num(a,b))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

TEST(add_mult, test001)
{
    int ret;


    MOCKER(mult_num)
        .expects(once())
        .will(returnValue(-1));

    ret = add_mult(2, 2);
    EXPECT_EQ(1, ret);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered this problem:
The operating system is Ubuntu
Kernel version: 3.13.0-107
The g++ version is: 5.4.0

The reason for this problem is that compile optimization is enabled at compile time, and optimization needs to be disabled in the compile options.

g++ -00 (the first is the letter O, the second is the number 0)